# More than 20 custom variables are used - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

i was woundering what happens when i send more than 20Custom Dimension in one hit even when i am using Free version of Google Analytics (not 360).

- Does the Custom Dimension get cut down so only 20 get passed?
- Does the Hit gets rejected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the admin section of the Google anlayitcs website you set up the custom dimensions and metrics you may or may not be sending with your requests.

If you try and send 5 and you only have 3 set up then five will simply be ignored by google analytics.   The same will happen if you have only 20 set up if you send 25.

The data is ignored and not stored in your account.